# undefined method `event_id' when using a belongs_to/has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, friendly-id

I'm creating a site that has events. Each event acts as a gallery and `has_many` images. Each image `belongs_to` and event.

I followed the [RailsCast #253 CarrierWave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?autoplay=true) gem. When I try to add a new image, it says

> undefined method `event_id' for # Image:0x7302438
>
> `<%= form_for @image, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>`
>
> `<%= f.error_messages %>`
>
> `<%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>`
>
> `<%= f.label :title %><br />`
>
> `<%= f.text_field :title %>`

Here is my image.rb

> `class Image < ActiveRecord::Base`
>
> > `attr_accessible :event_id, :title, :image`
> >
> > `validates :title, :image, :presence => :true, :uniqueness => :true`
> >
> > `belongs_to :event`
> >
> > `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`
>
> `end`

and the event.rb

> `class Event < ActiveRecord::Base`
>
> > `attr_accessible :title, :date, :about`
> >
> > `validates :title, :about, :date, :presence => :true`
> >
> > `validates :title, :uniqueness => :true`
> >
> > `has_many :images`
> >
> > `extend FriendlyId`
> >
> > `friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]`
>
> `end`

Comment: And does `event_id` exist in the `images` table?

Comment: Yes. I created a migration and ran a db:migrate

Comment: Isn't the column auto generated by the association?

Comment: A column in the table can't be generated by the association but a migrate should have done it, post your migrate code. Have you double checked in the database itself to be totally sure the column exists?

Comment: I always thought the association auto generated the column. But then again, I am a noob. 

Problem, no table column. Thanks @matt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this in a migration worked. Column wasn't added.

```
def up
   change_table :images do |t|
      t.references :event
   end
end
```